# On the existence of a certain type of function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I was asked in an analysis textbook the following question:

> Can there be a continuous and differentiable function $ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $ f(0) = 1 $ and $ f'(x) \geq f^2(x) $? We are asked to prove inexistence or supply an example. ($f^2$ is the squared function).

I have tried coming up with such a function but to no avail and I also could not supply proof of non-existence. I was thinking of standard tricks like a factor of integration or composing $ f $ with another function to disprove using the inequality. I thank all helpers.

Comment: Is $f^2(x)$ means square of $f(x)$ or composition function?

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya : sorry it's the squared

Comment: ^^  I was thinking it was just the second derivative, but yes clarification on this would be great

Comment: just clarified it means squared

Comment: reminder: continuity follows from differentiability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f'(x)\geq f(x)^2\ \forall x\in\mathbb [0,\infty)\iff\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}\geq1\forall x\in[0,\infty)\iff\frac{d}{dx}(-\frac{1}{f(x)})\geq1$ which gives $-\frac{1}{f(x)}+1\geq x$. Now $f$ is strictly increasiong on $[0,\infty)$. So LHS is bounded. But the RHS is unbounded. Contradiction.